# Google App Engine - Error vacuuming indexes

Tags: google-app-engine

I had an index that had status `error`, so following the docs I tried to vacuum my indexes to remove it.  When running appcfg.py to vacuum it I got this error message:

> Error 400: --- begin server output ---
>   Deleting a composite index failed:
>   ApplicationError: 1
>   --- end server output ---

Now all of my indexes are in error state.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must just have been a temporary issue, I retried the exact same command today and it worked.